# In Azure, is it possible to control access control (IAM) for a file shares using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, file, share

I have been trying to use Powershell to assign users access control privileges for a file share in Azure. What I have been doing is:

---

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Login to Azure

```
az login
```

Get User Information and isolate the User Principle Name

```
$UPN = (Get-AzADUser -StartsWith $UserName).UserPrincipalName
```

Get the row that contains Scope

```
$TempScope = az storage share-rm show -g $ResourceGroup --storage-account $StorageAccount --name $FileShareName | Select-String -Pattern '/subscriptions' -CaseSensitive
```

Change that row to a string

```
$TempScope = $TempScope | foreach {$_.ToString()}
```

Remove the first 8 characters

```
$scope = $TempScope.Substring(9)
```

Get Name of Role

```
$FileShareRole = Get-AzRoleDefinition $RoleName
```

Assign the role to the target identity with the specified scope

```
New-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName $UPN -RoleDefinitionName $FileShareRole.Name -Scope $scope
```

---

It has not been giving the user access to the file share but instead to microsoft.storage/storageaccounts/fileservices/shares.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can add Access Control to the file share. In the above-shared script, you are using the long approach to pull the resource ID of the file share. We have made some changes to the above script.

**Here is the Modified script to add Access Control to the file Share**:

```
$UserName="<UserName>"
$ResourceGroup="<RGName>"
$StorageAccount="<strgAccountName>"
$FileShareName="<FileShareName>"
$RoleName="Storage File Data SMB Share Reader"
$UPN = (Get-AzADUser -StartsWith $UserName).UserPrincipalName

$TempScope = az storage share-rm show -g $ResourceGroup --storage-account $StorageAccount --name $FileShareName --query id -o tsv
$FileShareRole = Get-AzRoleDefinition $RoleName
New-AzRoleAssignment -SignInName $UPN -RoleDefinitionName $FileShareRole.Name -Scope $scope
```

Here are the three [Azure built-in roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-auth-active-directory-domain-service-enable?tabs=azure-powershell#assign-access-permissions-to-an-identity) for granting share-level permissions to users:

- **Storage File Data SMB Share Reader**  allows read access in Azure Storage file shares over SMB.
- **Storage File Data SMB Share Contributor**  allows read, write, and delete access in Azure Storage file shares over SMB.
- **Storage File Data SMB Share Elevated Contributor**  allows read, write, delete and modify NTFS permissions in Azure Storage file shares over SMB.